# When I type in Chinese got error as "Multibyte character not supported"

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

[image: screenshot]

I am working in .net framework ascx page. When I give input in textbox with Chinese characters I got an error as "multibyte character not supported" in web application.

How to give Chinese characters in textbox...

```
<asp:Textbox ID="txtname" runat="server">/<asp:Textbox>
```

need to include specific code in above field to accept Chinese characters

Comment: You need to use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) to encode character. 
 Webpage do not support unicode. 
 See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: How to use this

Comment: Need to enable the specific textbox to accept Chinese characters

Comment: Does this help? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14ab42ed-ea7b-4bd2-95c1-55a15c4bbacf/how-to-set-unicode-format-in-textbox?forum=aspgettingstarted

Comment: No. I have already included utf -8 in globalization...I couldn't type or paste Chinese characters in textbox

Comment: Did you look at link in last posting?

Comment: Yes. But I don't know how to change font in textbox. I have tried Textboxname.font ="font name".but it not works

Comment: Try codeproject.  There is source code on tabs in left column besides the article : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774909/Fun-with-Unicode?force_isolation=true